# SQL Server question to check what query took the longest to run

Tags: sql, sql-server

ServiceJobTable

ServiceJObID, JobType, DateCreated, DateStarted, DateCompleted, BranchID, ErrorMessage, DateLastAttempt, DateDeferred, ParentServiceJobID,
MachineName, Scheduled, CreatedByStaffID, CreatedByMachineName, Description, EstimatedServiceJobItemCount, SupportWebSynRequired, MachineID, Priority

These are the images of how the table results look

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmSDx.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag7Oo.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEpCr.png)

This is the table I am using and with fields. I want to be able to find out for the last two weeks which ServiceJobs query takes the longest to run

```
SELECT TOP 10
    total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
        ,execution_count
        ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
        ,(SELECT
              SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                                                           WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                                                           ELSE statement_end_offset 
                                                       END -statement_start_offset)/2
                       ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
         ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
WHERE last_execution_time > DATEADD(week, -2, GETDATE())
ORDER BY AVG_Run_Time DESC
```

This is the generic query I used previously

Comment: What is your question? And please edit your query so we can read it.

Comment: I am finding it hard formatting it, so hope this helps https://pastebin.com/tKiKUMLF
My question how how can I find for the past two weeks which service jobs take the longest to run in terms of the query. I tried using the query above but I am sort of stuck on it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a SQL server performance counter for average execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164154/is-there-a-sql-server-performance-counter-for-average-execution-time)

Answer (score 1):

This is example query to to get top 10 resource appropriation query

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1, ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
        END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1),
    qs.execution_count,             -- Times query
    qs.total_logical_reads,             -- Total read bytes
    qs.last_logical_reads,              -- Total read bytes on last query
    qs.total_logical_writes,            -- Total write bytes
    qs.last_logical_writes,             -- Total write bytes on last query
    qs.total_worker_time,               -- Total time to running query
    qs.last_worker_time,                -- Total time to running last query
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    qp.query_plan           -- Query Plan 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_reads DESC -- logical reads
```

you can order by

```
ORDER BY qs.total_logical_writes DESC -- logical writes
```

or

```
ORDER BY qs.total_worker_time DESC -- CPU time
```

Hope to be useful to you!